# can not post data to apache localhost using android emulator

Tags: android, localhost, http-post, emulation

i am trying to post data on wamp's apache localhost using port no 8080 using below given code.

```
public class postdata extends Activity
{
    Button btnpost;
    EditText txtname,txtsalary;
    TextView lblstatus;
    String hostname;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setContentView(R.layout.main3);
        btnpost=(Button)this.findViewById(R.id.btnpost);
        txtname=(EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.txtname);
        txtsalary=(EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.txtsalary);
        final HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        final HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://127.0.0.1:8080/andy1/script2.php");
        btnpost.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0)
            {
                try
                {
                    List<NameValuePair> pair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
                    pair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("txtname",txtname.getText().toString()));
                    pair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("txtsalary",txtsalary.getText().toString()));
                    post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(pair));
                    HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Record Saved",1000).show();
                }
                 catch (ClientProtocolException e)
                    {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    }
                    catch (IOException e)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error in uploading",1000).show();
                    }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

whenever i run above code on emulator i got the following error.

```
12-03 10:10:51.237: E/AndroidRuntime(281): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-03 10:10:51.237: E/AndroidRuntime(281): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Host name may not be null
12-03 10:10:51.237: E/AndroidRuntime(281):  at org.apache.http.HttpHost.<init>(HttpHost.java:83)
12-03 10:10:51.237: E/AndroidRuntime(281):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.determineTarget(AbstractHttpClient.java:497)
12-03 10:10:51.237: E/AndroidRuntime(281):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
12-03 10:10:51.237: E/AndroidRuntime(281):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
12-03 10:10:51.237: E/AndroidRuntime(281):  at demo.network.postdata$1.onClick(postdata.java:65)
12-03 10:10:51.237: E/AndroidRuntime(281):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
12-03 10:10:51.237: E/AndroidRuntime(281):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
12-03 10:10:51.237: E/AndroidRuntime(281):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
12-03 10:10:51.237: E/AndroidRuntime(281):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-03 10:10:51.237: E/AndroidRuntime(281):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-03 10:10:51.237: E/AndroidRuntime(281):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
12-03 10:10:51.237: E/AndroidRuntime(281):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-03 10:10:51.237: E/AndroidRuntime(281):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
12-03 10:10:51.237: E/AndroidRuntime(281):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
12-03 10:10:51.237: E/AndroidRuntime(281):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
12-03 10:10:51.237: E/AndroidRuntime(281):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

i have also tried to use 10.0.0.2 as IP address as it was one of the solution posted in other post but did not work at all.
i have tried lot to solve this error using net but could not succeed.

Comment: just open same ip in browser and check is it working properly ?

Comment: Have you tried using 182.168.x.x? Go to CMD, type `ipconfig`, scroll up and there should be something like `IPv4 Address : xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`. Use that IP

Comment: Thank YOU your trick is working 100% perfectly but what to do if i dont have wifi or LAN at all to run the same code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you are running a Web server in the emulator you need to use the IP address of your development machine. Use `ifconfig` (Linux, etc.) or `ipconfig` (Windows) to find out what the address is. Should be something like '192.168.xxx.xxx` for a local network.

Or use 10.0.2.2 to refer to the development machine's loopback interface as suggested in the other answer. Here's the link to the relevant docs for the emulator: http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#networkaddresses

Answer (score 2):

For accessing localhost (development sys) you have to use **10.0.2.2** (not 10.0.0.2).

for more information look [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#networkaddresses)

Answer (score 0):

You can find ip from internet ..go to http://whatsmyip.net/ and this ip used in your project

final HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://**ip**:8080/andy1/script2.php");

Comment: This may not give the correct address if the development machine is NAT-ted or uses a proxy.

Comment: OP reported they are working locally. This won't work for that. All you will get is the IP that your service provider gives which is meaningless in this situation.